# Selecting elements of a vector based on two vectors of starting and ending positions matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I would appreciate your help with the following problem in matlab:
I have a vector and I would like to select parts of it based on the following two vector of start and end indices of parts:

```
aa = [1   22  41  64  83   105  127  147  170  190  212  233]
bb = [21  40  63  82  104  126  146  169  189  211  232  252]
```

Basically I would like to perform some function on `V(1:21)`, `V(22:40)`,... `V(233:252)`.
I have tried `V(aa:bb)` or `V(aa(t):bb(t))` where `t = 1:12` but I get only `V(1:21)`, probably because `V(22:40)` has 19 elements compared to `V(1:21)` which has 22 elements.

Is there a fast way of programming this?

Comment: what is the function you want to apply?

Answer (score 1):

Put your selection in a cell array, and apply your function to each cell:

```
aa = [1   22  41  64  83   105  127  147  170  190  212  233]
bb = [21  40  63  82  104  126  146  169  189  211  232  252]
V = rand(252,1); % some sample data

selV = arrayfun(@(t) V(aa(t):bb(t)), 1:12,'uniformoutput',false);
result = cellfun(@yourfunction,selV)
% or
result = cellfun(@(selVi) yourfunction(selVi), selV);
```

If the function you want to apply has scalar output to every vector input, this should give you an 1x12 array. If the function gives vector output, you'll have to include the `uniformoutput` parameter:

```
result = cellfun(@(selVi) yourfunction(selVi), selV,'uniformoutput',false);
```

which gives you a 1x12 cell array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this in a highly condensed form, you can write (in two lines, for clarity)

```
aa = [1   22  41  64  83   105  127  147  170  190  212  233]
bb = [21  40  63  82  104  126  146  169  189  211  232  252]
V = rand(252,1); % some sample data borrowed from @Gunther

%# create an anonymous function that accepts start/end of range as input
myFunctionHandle = @(low,high)someFunction(V(low:high));

%# calculate result
%# if "someFunction" returns a scalar, you can drop the 'Uni',false part
%# from arrayfun
result = arrayfun(myFunctionHandle(low,high),aa,bb,'uni',false)
```

Note that this may run more slowly than an explicit loop at the moment, but `arrayfun` is likely to be multithreaded in a future release.